# print result as hash in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
sql = select id,name from table
res = session.execute(sql)
for row in res:
    print row
```

this code print result of execute sql( without names) as array. How to print result as hash ? (with id,name)

Comment: Why don't you use `session.query(table)` instead of `session.execute()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
columns = ('id', 'name')

sql = 'select %s from table' % ','.join(columns)
res = session.execute(sql)
for row in res:
    rowDict = dict(zip(columns, row))
```